# Графические git-клиенты

Tags: git

подскажите какой гит графический удобнее использовать.

и все же что лучше консоль или графический клиент? ) спасибо

Comment: Кому как удобнее. Если в IDE есть git клиент - это самое лучшее решение.

Comment: TortoiseGit еше, например

Answer (score 6):

Все сильно зависит от операционной среды.

Если Вы под виндой, то тут консоль хорошо, но тяжело. Самый лучший клиент для начинающих под винду - это стандартный от [github](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#platform-windows) он и git установит, и клиент простенький, но функциональный доставит. Он конечно заточен на [github.com](http://github.com), но иногда это только плюс.

Под линукс - тут консоль - все наше. Я лично использую графические утилиты что бы посмотреть ситуацию, но ничего ими не модифицирую. В пакетах целая пачка - gitg, gitk, git-cola, giggle. Но в своей практике самый востребованный инструмент - **meld** - это обычная diff утилита, но она может и коммитить (и не только в git). Еще есть одна очень интересная утилита - tig. Это красивый визуализатор коммитов в консоле. (все упомянутые программы в большинстве линуксов ставятся стандартными средствами, в федоре - `yum install имя`)

На мак системах git обычно уже есть в стандартном наборе командных утилит. Клиент от github здесь также хорош.

Answer (score 5):

Рекомендую [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/). Очень удобный, есть интеграция с github и bitbucket.

[image: Скриншот 1]

[image: Скриншот 2]

Comment: я лично пробовал год назад эту программу в команде. Выкинули на следующий день. Программа попортила репозиторий, восстанавливали несколько часов.

Comment: у нас она тоже стоит, жутко висит, по началу хорошо пошло, простое переключение веток занимает несколько минут.

Comment: учитывая, что в git ветки переключаются быстро (ну как минимум под линуксом), то это все странно.

Comment: у нас в проекте много используется папка в паке и тд. хоть и добавила несколько в .gitignore, стало побыстрее, но все же. вот задалась вопросом. спасибо за ответ )

Comment: @ennet, "простое переключение веток занимает несколько минут" -- что? Из-за какой-то графической приблуды вы лишаетесь одного из главных преимуществ Git. Выкиньте ее в мусор.

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую SmartGitHg,очень удобный и понятный клиент.У него так же есть Diff тулза,SmartSynchronize,тоже удобная штука.На любую ось есть

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю добавить в копилку и web-оболочку [ungit](https://github.com/FredrikNoren/ungit). Сделана красиво и удобно, но умеет решать только основные задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Смотря как предполагается использовать  Git.
Многие коллеги (да почти все) используют SourceTree, приведенный выше.

Мне же проще использовать в качестве вьюера GitX, т.к. он очень простой и наглядный.
В нем удобно отменять или дополнять коммиты.

А вот сквош, редактирование и мерж, переход с ветки на ветку, чери-пики проще делать в консоли.
Разве можно чуть поднастроить Git, например добавив алиасы на комманды.

Answer (score 0):

Сам git имеет графическую оболочку:

```
команда git gui
```

А так, смотря где вы храните свои репозитории. Если локально, то этой оболочки хватает за глаза, если вы пользуетесь github.com, то у них есть свой красивый клиент, если bitbucket.org, то и они тоже имеют такую штуку, как SourceTree. С одной стороны графические оболочки приятнее для глаз, кажутся удобными, но в конечном итоге в них легко напутать что-нибудь, что потом будет сложно восстановить, так что лучше использовать консоль :)

Comment: ![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/qrjoCVV.png

Comment: Он есть, просто его нужно доустанавливать. Но он страшен как ....

Comment: Я даже и не подозревал, что он отдельно ставится.