# Как залить проекта на Git Hub без командной строки?

Tags: github

как загрузить файлы на Git Hub без командной строки

Comment: ну например скачать клиент и нажать в нем нужные кнопки

Comment: Еще есть хорошая штуковина tortoiseGit. Помогает в целом работь с git без командной строки

Comment: `Без командной строки` - а тогда как и чем вы хотите загрузить, [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/)?

Comment: @SwaD TortoiseGit не очень удобный (в отличие например от tortoise hg), под виндой я обычно git extensions использую. Вообще, куча gui клиентов есть, на все вкусы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Графические git-клиенты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/301507/%d0%93%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-git-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b)

Comment: А в чём проблема? Там есть кнопка «Add file»…